# History of five lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-topology, math-history, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am interested in the history of five lemma. Who was first to prove it and What was the purpose of proving it ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know [Weibel's](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/survey.pdf) note on the history of Homological Algebra? See page 17:

> The familiar "five-lemma" occurs for the first time on p. 16 of [ES]. (Its companion, the "snake lemma", first appeared in [CE].)

Nobody who looked at Cartan-Eilenberg book has been disappointed. It's an evergreen, no matter if it is 60 years old! :)

[ES]: S. Eilenberg and N. Steenrod, *Foundations of algebraic topology*, Princeton U. Press, Princeton, 1952.

[CE]: H. Cartan and S. Eilenberg, *Homological Algebra*, Princeton U. Press, 1956.